# What protections exist in the European Union against discrimination in an educational institution?

Tags: united-states, europe, disability

For those who aren't familiar with it, Section 504 of the Rehabilitation Act ("504" for short) is the U.S. law that protects the civil rights of students with disabilities at institutions that receive federal funds for any part of their budget.

Section 504 is important in its own right, and it was also an important step towards passage of the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA). Section 504 spelled the beginning of the end of "separate but equal" for people with disabilities.

Who is protected under 504? "Any person who (1) has a physical or mental impairment that substantially limits one or more major life activities, (2) has a record of such an impairment or (3) is regarded as having such an impairment. Major life activities include walking, seeing, hearing, speaking, breathing, learning, working, caring for oneself, and performing manual tasks."

For a fascinating and inspiring account of the history of 504, see the article [Short History of the 504 Sit-In](http://dredf.org/504-sit-in-20th-anniversary/short-history-of-the-504-sit-in/) and the video [Power of 504](https://vimeo.com/channels/504sitin).

504 is made up of two parts -- a law ("No otherwise qualified handicapped individual in the United States shall, solely by reason of his handicap, be excluded from the participation in, be denied the benefits of, or be subjected to discrimination under any program or activity receiving Federal financial assistance") and a set of regulations.

**Question: What is the equivalent of Section 504 in institutions of higher learning in the European Union?**

Comment: Also, [you have asked this on Law already](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5775/what-protections-exist-in-the-european-union-against-discrimination-in-an-educat). Cross-posting a question on multiple SE sites is [against SE policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: Although several laws are common across countries in the European Union several others aren't. I think this is the later case for protection of diabilities.

Comment: @ff524 - Apologies, I totally forgot I had tried it on Academia already.  Hmm.  May I delete the older one?  Maybe there will be more interest now.  I could relate it to Walter Wetlab.  I wouldn't mind deleting the one on Law -- frankly, I think I'm more likely to get useful information here than on Law for this particular question.

Comment: As pointed out by @Llopis, even if there can be an EU framework, then each country applies the EU framework through its own laws. For instance, for Italy, the relevant laws are listed [in this web page](https://didattica.polito.it/disabili/it/legislazione_e_link_utili) from the disability office of my university. Each link opens the text of the corresponding relevant law (of course in Italian). Even if it's in Italian, you can appreciated the length and the intricacy of its structure. So, I don't know what kind of answer we can give you.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - I would hope there is a simple guide available on university websites.  U.S. educational institutions that receive federal funds are required to make available such a guide.

Comment: @aparente001 The guide is about the services offered by the university, not about the law.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - Here is a good example page: https://disabilities.uchicago.edu/idea-ada-and-section-504.  It was a worthwhile exercise for me to find you a good example.  I was surprised how hard it was to find a good one.  I learned that more progress has been made in many universities with regard to gender discrimination than disablity discrimination.