# PhD student target of crazy department head

Tags: health

I got behind in my program because of illness. My university says it's ok for me to have extra time, but the department head of my program doesn't like this because he thinks all students must get a certain time. He wants to cut my funding, which would force me out of the program. He doesn't even care that right now I am doing good work. He just wants me gone. He spreads false rumors about me to other professors. The graduate director does nothing and says it is not his place.

My adviser likes me, but I don't think he is willing to always stand up to the department head. It is late in my program and I can not start over at another university. Thank you for your advice.

**Edit:** Getting behind was not my fault and my adviser knew of my illness. How can I persuade the department head that he should forget about my illness and let me work now so I can finish?

Comment: 1. What do the university rules say about the situation where a student gets behind because of illness? 2. When you say "extra time," do you mean extra time and extra funding? Did the university say it's OK for you to have extra time and the proportionate extra funding? 3. Is the department head able to unilaterally cut your funding? You say he "wants" to but he presumably has not done so yet.

Comment: @user1310503 The university says extra funding is ok too but they cannot force the department head. I need funding to continue. He has funding but he does not want to give it to me.

Comment: Have you contacted the department head to inform him about your situation during or after your illness?

Comment: @koalo If you mean illness, he knows and my adviser knew. Now he says I am behind and students need to finish on time. My work now he says is too late.

Comment: How much are you behind? How many months do you think it will take to finish your PhD and how long are you in the program already?

Comment: @koalo It will probably take another two years to finish. I was supposed to finish already.

Comment: I suggest that you (a) ask the university person what to do, as that seems to be the only person who is definitely on your side; (b) ask your advisor to stand up for you and help you; and (c) gather written evidence, especially about the department head spreading false rumors and the graduate director doing nothing to help, as this might be useful evidence that you can then show to other people to enlist their help or persuade them.

Comment: My sympathies for your situation. At StackExchange, we need a specific question to answer, and your post does not give one. Even if you add "what should I do?" that is too broad, you need to specify what you want the outcome to be. I.e. "what should I do to achieve X?"

Comment: Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" exactly as what @user2390246 says.

Comment: @scaaahu ok I will edit, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: [Related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/94987/due-to-my-depression-the-department-wants-to-kick-me-out-of-the-graduate-progra)

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered reaching out to your office of the Ombudsman/woman? Often times, they serve as the official/unofficial mediator when it comes to conflicts within an organization.

Comment: How would an Ombudsman stop the crazy behavior of the department head? There is no conflict, he just wants me gone.

Comment: @user113878 - because they can show the department head the discrepancy between university policy and their actions in an authoritative fashion.

Comment: @JonCuster I think policy is that the department head can do what he wants.

Comment: @user113878 - in the US at least there are tools such as university policy and state and federal law that may come in to play. Find them out and use them. Particularly if missing time was a result of medical issues. Between you and an ombuds you may be able to shake the right branch to get a realization that there is a potentially serious legal liability.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for the suggestion. I will check.

Answer (score 0):

in line with the previous answer, yes you should appeal, but if you truly have a department *head* as opposed to chair, you might have difficulty. At least in the US, heads wield much discretionary power while chairs serve as advocates. This may be partially why the graduate director isn't helping much. 
Why not make a candid, private, personal appeal to your head?  It's often the case that people can be softened when you become a person rather than just another student. Come armed with evidence of all you've done and reiterate your intention to graduate.

Comment: *At least in the US, heads wield much discretionary power while chairs serve as advocates.* This is entirely institution-dependent in my experience. At my undergrad, the department head did indeed wield a significant amount of power. At my current uni, the department head is more of an administrative role -- individual faculty members tend to wield as much (sometimes more, depending on the situation) power as the head does. Part of this might just be due to personalities, but I suspect it really does depend on the university/department.